# Regex: Match any character (including whitespace) except a comma

Tags: regex, string, sed, string-parsing

I would like to match any character and any whitespace except comma with regex.  Only matching any character except comma gives me:

```
[^,]*
```

but I also want to match any whitespace characters, tabs, space, newline, etc. anywhere in the string.

EDIT:

This is using sed in vim via :%s/foo/bar/gc.

I want to find starting from func up until the comma, in the following example:

```
func("bla bla bla"
  "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
"asdfasdfasdf", "more strings")
```

I

Comment: [^,]* does match until the comma?

http://rubular.com/r/sAq4ufTDe2

Comment: Your pattern seems to be OK. Just in case try once escaping comma, which might be required in the regexp engine you're using: `[^\,]*`

Comment: [^,]* matches until the comma or the end of the line for me.  I was having trouble trying to get it to continue searching until it finds the comma, even if it has to go through newlines

Comment: I am trying to do sed in vim via  :%s/foo/bar/gc.  Could that be an issue?

Comment: have you checked my suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion now, NeverHopeless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with `multiline` in `SED` using `RegEx`, you should look at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string).

**EDIT:**

In `SED` command, working with NewLine is a bit different. `SED` command support three patterns to manage multiline operations `N`, `P` and `D`. To see how it works see [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-51)(Working with Multiple Lines) explaination. Here these three operations discussed.

My guess is that `N` operator is the area of consideration that is missing from here. Addition of `N` operator will allows to sense `\n` in string.

An example from [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-nl):

> Occasionally one wishes to use a new line character in a sed script.
>   Well, this has some subtle issues here. If one wants to search for a
>   new line, one has to use "\n." Here is an example where you search for
>   a phrase, and delete the new line character after that phrase -
>   joining two lines together.
>
> (echo a;echo x;echo y) | sed '/x$/ { N s:x\n:x: }'
>
> which generates
>
> a xy
>
> However, if you are inserting a new line, don't use "\n" - instead
>   insert a literal new line character:
>
> (echo a;echo x;echo y) | sed 's:x:X\ :'
>
> generates
>
> a X
>
> y

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, but it may have been because I wasn't including enough information about my problem.  I've edited the original question.  I essentially want to find the string func( all the way to the comma.   I have :%s/func([^,]*,/bar/gc  but this doesn't seem to find across new lines

Comment: Or perhaps I wasn't sure where to put (?m).  I put it directly before the [^,]*.   As in :%s/func((?m)[^,]*,/bar/gc.  Is this correct?

Comment: In SED it won't work this way. check out this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?  Also, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include the relevant bits in your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you're trying to match a pattern over multiple lines.

Here's one way to do it in `sed` (pretty sure these are not useable within `vim` though, and I don't know how to replicate this within `vim`)

```
sed '
    /func/{
            :loop
            /,/! {N; b loop}
            s/[^,]*/func("ok"/
    }
' inputfile
```

Let's say `inputfile` contains these lines

```
func("bla bla bla"
  "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
"asdfasdfasdf", "more strings")
```

The output is

```
func("ok", "more strings")
```

---

**Details**:

- If a line contains `func`, enter the braces.
- `:loop` is a label named `loop`
- If the line does not contain `,` (that's what `/,/!` means)

  - append the next line to pattern space (`N`)
  - branch to / go to `loop` label (`b loop`)
- So it will keep on appending lines and looping until `,` is found, upon which the `s` command is run which matches all characters before the first comma against the (multi-line) pattern space, and performs a replacement.